# Remove duplicated code from same method in different objects

Tags: java, oop, object, collections, java-stream

I have 2 different objects, Parameter and Variable which are fields of Context.
I have also third object: ParameterBase which is not part of Context.
All 3 classes are auto-generated, I can't modify them.
All 3 classes have 2 fields: name and value which are of type String.
All 3 classes have getters and setters.

I implemented the following methods:

```
public static List<ParametersBase> removeDuplicate(List<ParametersBase> parameterList) {
    return new ArrayList<>(parameterList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                    ParametersBase::getParamName,
                    Function.identity(),
                    Utils::mergeDuplicate
            )
    ).values());
}

private static ParametersBase mergeDuplicate(ParametersBase a, ParametersBase b) {
    if (a.getParamValue().equals(b.getParamValue())) {
        return a;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error message");
    }
}
```

I want to do use this methods for the other 2 classes, so I did that:

```
private static void removeDuplicatesParams(Context context) {
    final List<ParametersBase> parameterList = emptyIfNull(
        context.getParameters()).stream()
        .map(parameter -> new ParametersBase()
            .paramName(parameter.getParamName())
            .paramValue(parameter.getParamValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<ParametersBase> distinctParameterList = removeDuplicate(parameterList);
    List<Parameter> distinctParametersList = distinctParameterList
        .stream().map(temp -> new Parameter().paramName(temp.getParamName())
            .paramValue(temp.getParamValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    context.setParameters(distinctParametersList);
}

private static void removeDuplicatesVariables(Context context) {
    final List<ParametersBase> parameterList = emptyIfNull(
        context.getVariables()).stream()
        .map(parameter -> new ParametersBase()
            .paramName(parameter.getParamName())
            .paramValue(parameter.getParamValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<ParametersBase> distinctParameterList = removeDuplicate(parameterList);
    List<Variable> distinctParametersList = distinctParameterList
        .stream().map(temp -> new Variable().paramName(temp.getParamName())
            .paramValue(temp.getParamValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    context.setVariables(distinctParametersList);
}
```

As you see, the two methods which I created are almost the same, but since I have 2 auto-generated classes I have to duplicate the code. Is there a way to make the code prettier? I'm using Java 8.

Comment: As I understand it, you could solve this problem with generics. Maybe this one can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890600/how-to-call-a-filter-and-sorting-method-for-several-classes-with-different-prope

Comment: @Hubi The case here is a little different because this problem involves complex objects, so mapping is needed.

Comment: Could you add `removeDuplicate` method source code? I think it can be generified.

Comment: public static List<ParametersBase> removeDuplicate(List<ParametersBase> parameterList) {
    return new ArrayList<>(parameterList.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(ParametersBase::getParamName, Function.identity(),
            Utils::mergeDuplicate))
        .values());
  }
private static ParametersBase mergeDuplicate(ParametersBase a,
      ParametersBase b) {
    if (a.getParamValue().equals(b.getParamValue())) {
      return a;
    } else {
      throw new Exception();
    }
  }
@Bananon

Comment: Is there any inheritance relationship between these three classes?

Comment: @Holger no relationship

Comment: @Amir Consider putting the sources of additional methods in the question itself. Use the [edit] button.

Answer (score 2):

You can generify `removeDuplicate` method:

```
private static <T> List<T> removeDuplicate(
        Collection<? extends T> parameterList,
        Function<? super T, String> name,
        Function<? super T, String> value
) {
    return new ArrayList<>(parameterList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.<T, String, T>toMap(
                    name,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (a, b) -> mergeDuplicate(a, b, value)
            )).values()
    );
}

private static <T> T mergeDuplicate(T a, T b, Function<? super T, String> value) {
    if (value.apply(a).equals(value.apply(b))) return a;
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error message");
}
```

And use it like this:

```
private static void removeDuplicatesParams(Context context) {
    context.setParameters(removeDuplicate(
            context.getParameters(),
            Parameter::getParamName,
            Parameter::getParamValue
    ));
}
```

---

Or you can apply the [adapter design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern):

```
private interface ParameterAdapter<T> {
    T original();
    String name();
    String value();
}

private static <T> List<T> removeDuplicate(
        Collection<? extends T> parameterList,
        Function<? super T, ? extends ParameterAdapter<T>> adapter
) {
    return parameterList.stream()
            .<ParameterAdapter<T>>map(adapter)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    ParameterAdapter::name,
                    Function.identity(),
                    Utils::mergeDuplicate
            )).values().stream()
            .map(ParameterAdapter::original)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static <T> ParameterAdapter<T> mergeDuplicate(
        ParameterAdapter<T> a,
        ParameterAdapter<T> b
) {
    if (a.value().equals(b.value())) return a;
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error message");
}
```

And use it like this:

```
private static void removeDuplicatesParams(Context context) {
    context.setParameters(removeDuplicate(
            context.getParameters(),
            Utils::adaptParameter
    ));
}

private static ParameterAdapter<Parameter> adaptParameter(Parameter parameter) {
    return new ParameterAdapter<Parameter>() {
        @Override
        public Parameter original() { return parameter; }

        @Override
        public String name() { return parameter.getParamName(); }

        @Override
        public String value() { return parameter.getParamValue(); }
    };
}
```

Comment: I used the  adapter design pattern you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: You must have been reading the OP’s mind, as nowhere in the question is the information that the whole operation is about removing duplicate names. Neither does it tell us the merge logic you’ve used.

Comment: @Holger I've asked to add `removeDuplicate` method source code and @Amir posted it as well as `mergeDuplicate` in a comments section.